# High and low objects using R's car library

Tags: r, recode

I'm trying to add a column which reads my dataframe's column and outputs a 1 if the element is bigger than a certain number (and a zero if the condition isn't met). However, this code doesn't seem to work: df is an existing dataframe.

```
df2 <- data.frame(df2, C=Recode(df$numbers, "hi:200=1; else=0")) ##C = numbers > 200 = 1
```

I'm using R's car library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you need?

```
df2 <- tibble(numbers = c(1, 200, 201))

df2$recoded <- ifelse(df2$numbers > 200, 1, 0)

df2

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# numbers recoded
# <dbl>   <dbl>
#   1       1       0
#   2     200       0
#   3     201       1
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R we can also do

```
df2$recoded <- as.integer(df2$numbers > 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` we could do:

```r
library(data.table)

df <- datasets::cars

setDT(df)

df[, numbers := ifelse(df$dist > 10, 1, 0)][1:10, ]

#>     speed dist numbers
#>  1:     4    2       0
#>  2:     4   10       0
#>  3:     7    4       0
#>  4:     7   22       1
#>  5:     8   16       1
#>  6:     9   10       0
#>  7:    10   18       1
#>  8:    10   26       1
#>  9:    10   34       1
#> 10:    11   17       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>